# Php: Can mysqli construct accept arrays?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am reading and learning MySQLi for database purposes. Previously I was using `PEAR::MDB2` for database connections, but it really no support and read that a using MySQLi is better. In `MDB2` you can pass a dsn array to the object to create a connection. I was wondering if you could do the same with MySQLi? Or does the connection have to be pass the parameters individually?

Comment: What does manual say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create array with params, but still have to pass them individually to mysqli_connect function:

```
<?php
$conn_params['myHost'] = 'localhost';
$conn_params['myUser'] = 'mysql_username';
$conn_params['myPass'] = 'mysql_password';
$conn_params['myDb'] = 'database_name';

$connection = mysqli_connect($conn_params['myHost'], $conn_params['myUser'], $conn_params['myPass'], $conn_params['myDb'], 2) or die("Couldn't connect to db!");
mysqli_query($connection, "set names utf8");

$q = "DELETE FROM `my_table` WHERE id='5'";
mysqli_query($connection, $q);
```